# fab fa-whatsapp appears in mobile device but i can't click on it

Tags: html

i have a problem with my fab fa-whatsapp font awesome. the problem is that it appears in desktop screen and i can click on it, it also appears in mobile screen but i can't click on it,on mobile screen it appears but it is not operating.here is my source code :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0701066555"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-5x" style="color:green;position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the link tag :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change HTML

```
<a style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;display:inline-block;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0701066555"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-5x" style="color:green;"></i></a>
```